# importing a method from a class in another code

Tags: python

I want to import a specific method of a class in a file to another file of course in the same directory, so i tried this following way

```py
from file1 import Class1
from file1 import Class1.method
```

it doesn't work and it shows me a syntax error on the python kernel on the level of the dot between Class1 and method

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: You can't import a method without the class, that would make no sense. Just import the class and use it normally.

Comment: You cannot import a method from a class. You can import the class and then call the method - ‘Class.method()’. If you define the method as a staticmethod then you can call it without having to instantiate an instance of the class

Comment: If you can use a method without its parent class then you need to decide whether it actually belongs in that class at all

Answer (score 2):

```
from file1 import Class1

exampleClassObject = Class1()
rungMethod = exampleClassObject.method
```

You need to create an instance of the class before you can run it's method and cannot import it directly

Answer (score 1):

You can not import a method that way. The first and foremost thing is, if you want to import just a function, that should be static otherwise it makes no sense to import that. The only way you can use a static function is:

```
from file1 import Class1

# function call if method is static
Class1.method()
```

If the function is not static. You need to instantiate an object before calling the function.

```
# when method is not static
class1_obj = Class1()
class1_obj.method()
```